# Excel 2007 Chart - Super Simple Chart what am I doing wrong?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have two columns.

The first column begins with "Year" followed by well years (1999, 2000, 2001, etc.).

The second column has a title of "Revenue" and is contains revenue values ($12.1M, $13.2M, $23.1M, etc.).

How do I do a simple bar chart where the Y axis is years and the X axis is revenue values.

This seems super simple but when I highlight and click on the insert bar chart it won't come out.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to reproduce the problem you mentioned.

My guess is that, **Excel has interpreted the YEAR column (say column A) as part of the data**, because Excel will try to interprete any number-like value as number.

Here is a **simple trick** that solve the problem.

1. Change the value in YEAR column (ie. 1999, 2000, 2001, ...) to any text (ie. A, B, C, ...)
2. Highlight both columns (eg. A1:B10), and press the chart button as usual.
   (As Excel cannot convert A/B/C to any number, it will make the A/B/C as axis label correctly.)
3. Change the text back to the YEAR (1999, 2000, ...)

Alternatively, **if you cannot change any cell value**, you can manually set it in the chart wizard.

1. Highlight ONLY the REVENUE column (eg. B1:B10), and press the chart button.
2. Set A2:A10 as axis label in the wizard, and continue with the chart wizard

(As I only have Excel 2003 at the moment, I will update the answer if there is any difference in Excel 2007.)

Comment: I just tested this method with Excel 2007 and it worked. Nice!